# Post notification from specific object - cocoa touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, notifications

So I have this function inside `NotificationManager` class.

```
-(void) postNotificationForClassName:(NSString*)className withObjects:(NSArray*)objects withError:(BOOL)withError
{

    notificationName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"didLoad%@",className];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:notificationName object:self];
}
```

now, let's say I have 2 classes , A and B.

from A's method foo() I do the following:

```
[[NotificationManager sharedManager]
    postNotificationForClassName:@"A" withObjects:objects withError:NO]
```

from B's method goo() I do the following:

```
[[NotificationManager sharedManager] 
    postNotificationForClassName:@"A" withObjects:objects withError:NO]
```

Now, I'm curious what should I do in case I want to listen only to notifications being posted from Class A.

Is this suppose to work ?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self 
       selector:@selector(didLoadData:) 
           name:@"didLoadA" object:classAObject];
```

Cause I'm assuming that when I'm calling

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:notificationName object:self];
```

and I pass the "self", then the "self" will be the `NotificationManager` and not the class A or B that called the `NotificationManager` method.

Am I right or wrong here ? and if I'm right, is there a way to do what I want to accomplish?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to pass `@"A"` as the class name in `-goo`? (Method names don't include parentheses.)

Comment: Yes I did, it's only for the example to show the same notification being posted from 2 different classes (A and B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is a special variable, always referring to the object that received the message currently being handled. In `NotificationManager`'s `-postNotificationForClassName:withObjects:objectswithError:withError:`, `self` is a `NotificationManager` (or descendent). As for `self` in the call to `-addObserver:...`, it depends on what method the call occurs in.

As you've noticed, `-addObserver:...` lets you monitor notifications from specific objects. You could use this to monitor messages from `A`s if you use the class `A` as the object:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self 
       selector:@selector(didLoadData:) 
           name:@"didLoadA" object:[A class]];
```

However, you'll also need to change the notification sender in `-postNotificationForClassName:withObjects:objectswithError:withError:`.

```
-(void)postNotificationForClassName:(NSString*)className 
                        withObjects:(NSArray*)objects 
                          withError:(BOOL)withError
                               from:(id)sender
{

    notificationName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"didLoad%@",className];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:notificationName object:[sender class]];
}
```

Comment: So, is there a way to make certain observer get notifications only from class A or not ? meaning foo() will pop his notification handler but goo() won't.

Comment: @Idan: It depends on the answer to my request for clarification above.

Comment: answered to you at the same time :)